# How do I create a work item in rtc with curl?

Tags: java, curl

I need to create a `RTC` work item in my code in Java, using `cURL`.

How do I do this?‏

Thanks!

Comment: Tried reading the [manual](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ProgrammaticWorkItemCreation)?